# Drawing a line from the first point to last point in Google Charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I've built this chart using Google Charts API.

[image]

I would like to draw a line from the first point to the last one to obtain the (hand made) following.

[image]

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be achieved by adding another column, or series, to the data table.

once the data has loaded,
add another column to the data table for the new series.

```
data.addColumn('number', 'y1');
```

then we can set value of the first and last rows to the same value as the first series.

```
data.setValue(0, 2, data.getValue(0, 1));
data.setValue(data.getNumberOfRows() - 1, 2, data.getValue(data.getNumberOfRows() - 1, 1));
```

in order to draw an actual line between the two points,
we need to set the following option...

```
var options = {
  interpolateNulls: true
};
```

this will allow the line to connect the two points.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y0');
  data.addRows([
    [0, 0],   [1, 10],  [2, 23],  [3, 17],  [4, 18],  [5, 9],
    [6, 11],  [7, 27],  [8, 33],  [9, 40],  [10, 32], [11, 35],
    [12, 30], [13, 40], [14, 42], [15, 47], [16, 44], [17, 48],
    [18, 52], [19, 54], [20, 42], [21, 55], [22, 56], [23, 57],
    [24, 60], [25, 50], [26, 52], [27, 51], [28, 49], [29, 53],
    [30, 55], [31, 60], [32, 61], [33, 59], [34, 62], [35, 65],
    [36, 62], [37, 58], [38, 55], [39, 61], [40, 64], [41, 65],
    [42, 63], [43, 66], [44, 67], [45, 69], [46, 69], [47, 70],
    [48, 72], [49, 68], [50, 66], [51, 65], [52, 67], [53, 70],
    [54, 71], [55, 72], [56, 73], [57, 75], [58, 70], [59, 68],
    [60, 64], [61, 60], [62, 65], [63, 67], [64, 68], [65, 69],
    [66, 70], [67, 72], [68, 75], [69, 80]
  ]);


  data.addColumn('number', 'y1');
  data.setValue(0, 2, data.getValue(0, 1));
  data.setValue(data.getNumberOfRows() - 1, 2, data.getValue(data.getNumberOfRows() - 1, 1));

  var options = {
    interpolateNulls: true
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Great!!! Thanks for all the infos!